# JavaFX: How to invalidate an Observable object that contains a list of other Observable objects

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm a bit confused with listeners in javaFX.

I have a class (let's call it ObservedContainer) that implements Observable, which contains a list of some objects that are also Observables:

```
public class ObservedContainer implements Observable {
  ArrayList<AnotherObservableClass> someOtherClasses;
  (...observable implementation omitted for brevity)
}
```

I can invalidate the class when I add or remove something from the array - that's ok:

```
public class ObservedContainer implements Observable {
  ArrayList<AnotherObservableClass> someOtherClasses = new ArrayList<>();
  (...observable implementation omitted for brevity)

  public void addAnotherObservableClass(AnotherObservableClass a){
    someOtherClasses.add(a);
    fireInvalidationEvent();
    // This just notifies all listeners that the object has changed
  }

  public void removeAnotherObservableClass(AnotherObservableClass a){
    someOtherClasses.remove(a);
    fireInvalidationEvent();
  }  
}
```

But how do I have it fire the invalidation event when an object in the array gets modified ? Should the `ObservedContainer` object subscribe as a listener to each `AnotherObservableClass` object, and react to that ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class that should handle this for you: [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)

The [`FXCollections.observableArrayList` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-) can be used to trigger update changes on a modification of a property of a element in the list.

#### Example

```
ObservableList<Node> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(node -> new Observable[] { node.translateXProperty() });
```

Would trigger the listeners, if the `translateX` property of one of the list's elements is modified.

If you insist on wrapping the list in your own class, you could simply add a listener that triggers the invalidation event of the wrapper:

```
list.addListener((Observable o) -> fireInvalidationEvent());
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this doesn't seem to work when I modify a property of the underlying objects? I would like the list to be invalidated when *any* property of *any* object in the list gets modified.